# Javascript in CEWP on EditForm.aspx not kicking off in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form, content-editor-web-part, cewp

In our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise environment I tried adding Javascript into a Content Editor Web Part on a custom List's EditForm.aspx page, and for some reason the code only runs when the form is in "Edit" mode (i.e. to move web parts around). Otherwise nothing happens.

Furthermore, this strange behavior only happens in Chrome. In IE8 and greater, the code executes just fine when opening the form, without need to "Edit Page".

Is there a way to force it to run when the form is opened in non-edit mode? I am using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction,"sp.js");` to kick off the code, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question with more details. It's 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Publishing pages it was discovered that [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not work properly in SharePoint 2013

So, the solution is to replace:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func,"sp.js");
```

with:

```
// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', func);
```

Please follow [SP.ClientContext object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245759.aspx) description for more details